# Cucumber script to load readed data into a list

Tags: ruby, cucumber, watir

I am fairly new to using cucumber for automated testing. So far the tasks I was given to do only required filling in values into a form and comparing expected results.

I was wondering instead of filling in values could cucumber do the opposite and read values?

Imagine a table on a webpage with a column of IDs (like the one below). I would like to read all the IDs of that table and store it in a list. The reason is I would like to ultimately then go through the list of IDs look it up on the table again and click on the View link of each of these IDs. This could sound weird but there is more to it then that. For now I only need to know if I could collect the IDs in column 2 and stick it into a list then iterate through the list.

[image]

Would that be possible?

My knowledge of cucumber automated testing is that its used for extensive low-level interface regression testing. So like simple laborious tasks. Would what I want to do be out of the scope of cucumber?

I am using cucumber, ruby and watir together for these automated tests.

---

html code of the table:

```
<table id="row" class="data">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Action</th>
        <th>Book ID</th>
        <th>...</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td class="actionColumn">
            <input id="014112854edb_45ed_68e1d7bf" name="submit.view" class="action_link" onclick=" return setField('bookSearchResultForm','selectedId','123'); " type="submit" size="" value="View">
        </td>
        <td>123</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even">
        <td class="actionColumn">
            <input id="014112854ede_52cb_3ef325a7" name="submit.view" class="action_link" onclick=" return setField('bookSearchResultForm','selectedId','444'); " type="submit" size="" value="View">
        </td>
                    <td>444</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="odd">
        <td class="actionColumn">
            etc etc
        </td>
        <td>443</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: What does the Scenario description and the Gherkin (Given/When/Then) part look like?

Comment: Given the URL "_____"
When I add "_______" to username
When I add "_______" to password
And click the Login button
Then "page title" should be mentioned on the page"

this is when i should be on the table page and proceed to get all the ids from the table and stick them in a list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are already using Cucumber to read values - ie I assume that is how you are checking expected results.

For example, Watir can get the value of all values in the first column of a table.

```
ids = @browser.table.tbody.trs.collect{ |tr| tr.td.text }
```

You might use this in a Cucumber step to check that some specific id exists somewhere in the table.

```
Then /the list of ids should include (.*)/ do |expected_id|
  ids = @browser.table.tbody.trs.collect{ |tr| tr.td.text }

  ids.should include?(expected_id)
end
```

Note that you could use the above Watir code without Cucumber. For example, you could use it in a stand-alone script for scraping information from a page, to help you gather information during your manual testing, etc.

Update - View Links:

Putting Cucumber aside, getting the list of ids to iterate through the view links would be:

```
# Get the 2nd cell value in each row
ids = @browser.table.tbody.trs.collect{ |tr| tr.td(:index => 1).text }

# Click through each view link
ids.each do |id|
  # Find the row that contains the id
  row = @browser.table.tbody.trs.find{ |tr| tr.td(:text => id).present? }

  # Click the link in that row
  row.button(:text => 'View').click

  # Do whatever you want on the other page
  # Then make sure to return to this page
end
```

Comment: i am testing this out atm. what if I wanted the second column instead of the first? and its a little more complicated then I explained it initially so i updated my question for more info

Comment: i am thinking using ur code after i get the list of ids, i could do a ids.each loop where i write a routine to be executed for each id. i think that could achieve what i want ultimately

Comment: I added an example of what I think you want to do.

Comment: i am getting this exception.

Unable to locate element, using {:tag_name=>["a"], :text=>"View"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
./features/step_definitions/copy quotes/copyQuotes.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
./features/step_definitions/copy quotes/copyQuotes.rb:4:in `each'
./features/step_definitions/copy quotes/copyQuotes.rb:4:in `/copy list of quotes from quote table/'
features\Copy_Quotes_Lifemap.feature:23:in `Then copy list of quotes from quote table'

is there a way to debug this stuff? ie I want to see if the list actually grabbed the ids properly

Comment: Thanks for helping me yet again btw

Comment: You can output the ids by adding a `p ids` after you collect them.

Comment: The exception might be occurring because some rows do not have the view link. For example, if you have a heading row or certain footer rows that do not have the link, they would throw an exception. Instead of picking all rows (ie `trs`), you might need to filter the trs selected. For example if all the data rows have a certain class, you could do `trs(:class => 'class')`.

Comment: using google chrome i inspected the table and all data rows are in the tag <tbody> (header row is not), and all trs are marked with class "even" or "odd". so i added row = @browser.table.trs(:class=>'odd' || :class=>'even').find{ |tr| tr.td(:text => id).present? } which just ended up giving me a syntax error. i also managed to output the ids by using p ids like you said and it worked out fine except the tables had many pages and it only collected the IDs from the first page

Comment: If all the rows in the tbody are what you want, use `@browser.table.tbody.trs.find{tr.td(:text => id).present?}`. If you need to do it by class, I believe it would have to be `@browser.table.trs(class => /odd|even/).find{tr.td(:text => id).present?}`.

Comment: both your previous suggestions worked the only part now is it won't click on the link. here's the specific code for the View button
<input id="014112854edb_45ed_68e1d7bf" name="submit.view" class="action_link" onclick=" return setField('bookSearchResultForm','selectedId','123'); " type="submit" size="" value="View">

Comment: and here is the exception  undefined method `link' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError).

Comment: The code works for me when I use the table row you supplied for your previous question. Based on the exception, no row is being found. But without seeing your table, I am not sure how to debug that. Also I changed the code to find a View button instead of a View link.

Comment: yea i tried that too from a previous question. they are actually different tables but very very similar. i will add some code to hopefully help, thanks a lot again.

Comment: The code works for me with the table you supplied. In the loop, try adding a `p id`. This will help determine which row it is failing on. Perhaps that row is different.

Comment: found out y! it is because the list of ids grabbed the header anyways so the very first thing it was looking for was "Book ID" and of course when we're in the tbody looking for a row with "Book ID" it couldn't find anything. in other words i forgot to add tbody when collecting the ids. i fixed that and everything works now! thanks =]